# boot loop with complete(write) faliure

Tags: root-access, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

My phone has been rooted with custom ROM resurrection remix 5.8.4. it is a samsung galaxy s4 mini gt 19190. it is stuck in a boot loop in both normal and in twrp recovery mode. i tried changing my recover and my firmware but they show this complete(write) faliure

Comment: This isn't really a question, more of a statement of facts as you understand them... what are you asking, how it happened, how to restore it to stock, how to boot TWRP, or something else?

Comment: Most likely, you will need to restore to stock with ODIN/Heimdall, and if that doesn't work then the device's internal storage chip has likely failed and the handset will need to be retired/replaced or have the mainboard replaced (which is often more expensive or difficult than replacing the device, especially on of this age).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Recovery and do "Wipe" or "Factory Reset"

it should solve the problem